# Angularjs + bootstrap css, $invalid property doesn't work, whats wrong?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I've a form with input controls which I need validate, but the angularjs validation doesn't work as I expected, something I'm doing wrong

This is a control of my form, between tags

```
<form id="addServiceForm" name="addServiceForm">
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty}">
    <label class="control-label" for="qty">Cantidad</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></span>
        <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa cantidad" ng-model="service.quantity" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <span ng-show="addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span ng-show="addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty" id="helpBlockQty" class="help-block">La cantidad es requerida.</span>
</div>
</form>
```

If I assign `ng-class = "'has-error'"`  directly it works as expected, but when I put conditions like this:

`ng-class="{'has-error':addServiceForm.description.$invalid && addServiceForm.description.$dirty}"`

Nothing occurs, it doesn't works as I need.

I'm begginer using angularjs and bootstrap, please be patient with me =(

Comment: Edit: when I put conditions like: addServiceForm.**qty**.$invalid

Comment: Did you put the `name` attribute of the form to be `addServiceForm` and the name of the input to be `description`?

Comment: It will help if you put some JSFiddle code.

Comment: Yes I've a form addService and the input name is in this case qty, sorry for the error in my typing. 

Thank you for the tips

Comment: Have you typed something in the input field and then erased it? Because your condition tests that the input is invalid AND dirty. It will be dirty only if you type something in he field.

Comment: I guess you need to first input something (to make it `$dirty`) then empty it, to make `ng-require` take care of it.

Comment: Yes I typed in the input and then erased it, however the class is not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there is no condition set on your `input` such as `ng-minlength` to tell Angular when `.$valid` or `.$invalid` should return true. So Angular just defaults to `ng-minlength="1"` and the error is never displayed inless you delete all letters.

You should also look into the `$submitted` method, it is very nice for form validation.

```
<form id="addServiceForm" name="addServiceForm">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty}">
                 <label class="control-label" for="qty">dirty: {{addServiceForm.qty.$dirty}} invalid: {{addServiceForm.qty.$invalid}}</label>
                 <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                     <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa cantidad" ng-model="service.quantity" ng-required="true"
                            ng-minlength="4"/>
                 </div>
                 <span ng-show="addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
                  Another Div
                 </span>
                 <span ng-show="addServiceForm.qty.$invalid && addServiceForm.qty.$dirty" id="helpBlockQty" class="help-block">La cantidad es requerida.</span>
             </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Err `ng-required="true"`is present on the input. And no, angular doesn't defaults to `ng-minlength="1"`.

Comment: Yes but how should the form determine whether the `input` is `$valid` or `$invalid`? You didn't set any condition

Comment: Thank you for answer
I added the code you give me, but in the label just appears dirty: invalid:
I can't do angularjs read the property $invalid or $dirty

Comment: I added to my js file a function to read this properties... something like:

        $scope.readProperty = function () {

            console.log('addServiceForm.qty'.$invalid);
            console.log('forms.addServicesForm.qty'.$dirty);

        }

I think it is assumed thath in console should be appear a boolean like false or true

But just appears 
undefined
undefined

I'm so sorry if this is some easy, I don't want disturb, I just want my code runs correctly

Comment: @SuperVeetz `ng-required="true"` means that the input is invalid if it's empty, and valid if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

finally I could resolve the problem, for a unknown reason the form could not be positioned immediately after the div with the controller inside. I just moved the code at last part of my html before the closing div, and with this move my form works exactly as I need.

Thanks for all your comments and recommendations.

If someone knows why this is necessary, I hope you share.

Regards